# LINQ Extension method .SelectMany() written in another form

Tags: linq

How to write this LINQ expression in another .SelectMany() form ?

```
var result = 
                    from a in numbersA
                    where a < 3
                    from b in numbersB
                    where b < 5
                    select new { a, b };
```

?

`var result = numbersA.Where(x => x < 3).Select`.. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a rough translation of what the compiler would do:

```
var result = numbersA.Where(a => a < 3)
                     .SelectMany(a => numbersB, (a, b) => new { a, b })
                     .Where(z => z.b < 5)
                     .Select(z => new { z.a, z.b });
```

Now you can write this more efficiently as:

```
var result = numbersA.Where(a => a < 3)
                     .SelectMany(a => numbersB.Where(b => b < 5),
                                 (a, b) => new { a, b });
```

... but that's not what the compiler would do. It's not clear whether your aim is to see what the compiler does, or to just write a query.

Comment: I always forget that `SelectMany` overload.

Comment: You just presented both options anyway.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
var result = numbersA.Where(a => a < 3).SelectMany(a =>
    numbersB.Where(b => b < 5).Select(b => new { a, b }));
```

Note that it maybe be more efficient to filter `numbersB` *once* only:

```
var filteredB = numbersB.Where(b => b < 5).ToArray();
var result = numbersA.Where(a => a < 3).SelectMany(a =>
    filteredB.Select(b => new { a, b }));
```